# Type casting error in treeView in javafx by using public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) method

Tags: javafx, casting, treeview

I am new in JavaFx. In a treeview, if I add a treeItem of string(`TreeItem<String>`) we can able to edit, add or delete a node by using the follwoing code.

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
    @Override
    public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
        return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl(treeView);
    }
});
```

But if the treeItems can be of any type(`TreeItem<?>`), we can get the tree but not able to view, not able to add or delete the node. It throws type casting error. Please share your suggesstions. My code is as below,
Here

```
public TreeItem<?>     root;

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>((TreeItem<String>) tree.root);
    treeView.setEditable(true);
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl(treeView);
        }
    });

    box.getChildren().add(treeView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    private TextField textField;
    private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();

    public TextFieldTreeCellImpl(TreeView<String> p) {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Add Nodes");
        MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete Nodes");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
        addMenu.getItems().add(deleteMenuItem);
        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                TreeItem newNodes =  p.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                boolean remove = newNodes.getParent().getChildren().add(newNodes);
            }
        });
        deleteMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                TreeItem removeNodes =  p.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                boolean remove = removeNodes.getParent().getChildren().remove(removeNodes);
                System.out.println("Remove");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

       if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {

                if (textField != null) {

                    textField.setText(getString());
//              }
//              setText(null);

                setGraphic(textField);

            } else {

                setText(getString());

                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                if (
                    !getTreeItem().isLeaf()&&getTreeItem().getParent()!= null
                ){

                    setContextMenu(addMenu);

                }

            }

        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });  

    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is impossible. If you allow arbitrary content to be displayed in the `TreeView`, you cannot define a proper method of converting from `String` to the target type (since the target type is unknown). Also there isn't a method to display any type nicely. `toString` is as close as it gets, but if it's not overwritten, the result won't be nice. (e.g. for arrays).BTW: You can achieve the functionality of your `TextFieldTreeCellImpl` with  [`TextFieldTreeCell`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTreeCell.html) without even extending it...